# Unable to execute POST request on AWS API Gateway

Tags: curl, postman, aws-api-gateway

I'm unable to execute the following post request using CURL or from Node
`curl -i -H "Host : {id}.execute-api.eu-west-1.awmazonaws.com" -X POST "https://{id}.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Staging/Generate?user={user}&secret={secret}"`.
The same url works when invoked from Postman.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate on your API GW. Is your API Gateway enabled with IAM authentication? If yes, you need to have signature verification -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html

You need to calculate a signature for your access key+secret and pass to AWS to verify the signature.